# Excel changing decimal places on number cells when I edit the cell's formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet with thousands of number cells, all formatted "Number, 3 decimal places, use 1000 Separator ( )".

Starting a few days ago, if I edit a formula in any of these cells to reference another cell, Excel will change the decimal places to 14.

For example, "=C$53^$B$4" => "=C$53^$B$10" will cause this.

I am not aware of any settings being changed.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

**EDIT**

This does not happen on all cells. I cannot see a difference between the ones it does and doesn't occur on.

Comment: I do have macros. The format remains as numeric. I mean Separator( ) because I'm not in the US and we use a space in place of a comma.

Comment: I also get the famous "The picture is too large and will be truncated" error when copying any row in any spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that problem. As for the formatting, I don't know. But I'm upgrading to the latest version of Office, so we'll see how it goes.